# Translating constructions of the form "a lot to..." and "little to..."

Tags: грамматика

I was wondering how to translate constructions of the form "*a lot to ...*" or "*little to ...*" in Russian. For example "*I have little to say*", "*I have a lot to do*".

Based on the examples on [this site](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/a+lot+to+say) I would say that "*I have a lot to say*" can be translated both as "*Мне много сказать*" and "*Мне много что сказать*". Is this understanding correct? Is there a difference in meaning? Perhaps there is a third way to form such sentences?

Comment: "много**е** сказать" and "много **что** сказать". "Много сказать", though not ungrammatical in itself, in most cases would be too colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

These constructs don't translate idiomatically to Russian, at least not verbatim.

"I have a lot to say" would be *мне есть, что сказать* (literally "I have something to say"), or, rather, *мне найдётся, что сказать* (literally, "I will find something to say").

> - Ну, я по робости сперва слово-два, дальше больше, кивает он, я осмелела. А мне есть что порассказать.
> - Куда бы вы ни пошли, мне всюду с вами по дороге, потому что мне есть что вам сказать, потому что вас-то я и искал целый день.
> - ― Что у меня с избытком найдется что сказать ― за это ручаюсь, отчего же я нем?

"I have little to say" would be *мне нечего сказать* (literally, "I have nothing to say"):

> - Однако теперь у меня складывается впечатление, что ему просто нечего сказать в свое оправдание.
> - Мне нечего сказать по этому поводу, кроме того, что такая экономия оборачивается угрозой человеческим жизням и дорогостоящим ремонтом.

Note that "little to say" is usually used as a meiosis (understatement used as a figure of speech), and what people really mean when they say "little to say" is "nothing to say". This meiosis has rooted in the English language but not in Russian.

The phrase *найдётся, что сказать*, is, on the contrary, a meiosis in Russian but not in English. It is used in the situations when you literally don't have to look around for something to say.